# joomla: how is the CSS generated?

Tags: css, joomla

i made a website that looks like this www.yoursdproperty.com

i would like to know how the CSS is generated? where is it generated? how can i edit the settings that generate the CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a while since I looked at Joomla, but (once you're logged into it) isn't there a "Template Manager" through which you edit the CSS?

EDIT: Just checked it out via http://www.opensourcecms.com/, it is indeed "Template Manager", under "Extensions" on the main menu. Select your template, then click the "Edit CSS" button on the top right.

Comment: perhaps you can also answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173547/css-increasing-size-of-holder-or-what-ever-its-called

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Joomla generates (=compiles) style sheets out of the box.

Look into your source code:

```
<link href="/templates/system/css/system.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/templates/system/css/general.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/templates/pjo_joomlaforall/css/template_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

you should be able to edit these without problems?

Comment: hey pekka thanks so much again for helping, the thing i think that joomla is probably making those

Comment: Hmm. I don't know Joomla well enough to know whether there is any automatic generation going on. Anyway, if you need to overwrite some rules, the easiest thing would be setting up a style sheet file of your own, and including it after the aforementioned ones. In that file, you'd just overwrite the classes you need.

Answer (score 1):

This may be applicable now to users on 1.7 or 2.5.  You can edit the CSS in the browser by going to Extension/Template Manager, and then clicking the Templates option (instead of styles).  Click on your particular template and all the css files will be listed down the right.  Some have alot.  As an example, the beez_20 default template has 16 css files.  You could download them all and search them for the selectors you are looking for.  For beez_20 it is personal.css which has most of them.  Source: http://www.itlearning.net

Answer (score 0):

Joomla doesn't make any "automatic generation" of css.  The css are in the stylesheets at the url shown.